# trying to create view in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Can somebody help me create a view for the following code?

It's showing error near order by

```
    USE [ERPV9]
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwSupplierReport]
    AS
    SELECT
    CT.TransDate, 
    CASE WHEN DN.DocNo IS NOT NULL THEN DN.DocNo ELSE CT.SupplierReference                           END AS DocNo,
   TT.TransTypeName AS [Description],
   RP.ChequeNo,
   CASE WHEN CT.TransTypeID = 20 THEN (MAX(CT.TotalAmount + CT.TotalTax + CT.Freight)) ELSE 0 END AS Debit, 
   CASE WHEN CT.TransTypeID IN (21,22) THEN MAX(CT.TotalAmount + CT.TotalTax + CT.Freight) ELSE 0 END AS Credit,
   (SUM(MAX(CT.TotalAmount + CT.TotalTax + CT.Freight)) OVER (ORDER BY CT.TransDate, CT.SuppTransID)) AS Balance 
   FROM SupplierTransactions CT
   LEFT JOIN DocumentNos DN ON CT.CompanyID = DN.CompanyID AND CT.TransTypeID = DN.TransTypeID AND CT.TransNo = DN.TransNo
   INNER JOIN TransactionTypes TT ON CT.CompanyID = TT.CompanyID AND CT.TransTypeID = TT.TransTypeID
   LEFT JOIN ReceiptsAndPayments RP ON CT.CompanyID = RP.CompanyID AND CT.TransTypeID = RP.TransTypeID AND CT.TransNo = RP.TransNo
   WHERE CT.CompanyID = 'ccaa3e3f-4486-4465-b5a1-723f647ead17' AND SupplierCode = 'SR0001 ' AND TransDate >= '2013-3-26' AND TransDate < '2015-2-27'
```

Comment: 1. What's the exact error? 2. Where exactly is the error occurring?

Comment: 1.not able to create the view 2.its showing **Incorrect syntax near 'order'.**

Comment: Does that select work as a separate clause?

Comment: I don't think you can use SUM() with OVER(ORDER BY).   Why do you even have an ORDER BY in the view?   what purpose is it supposed to serve?

Comment: 1.its a normal query ... i want to convert it to a view so that i can get the data depending up on conditions ... **purpose  is to produce reports **

Comment: i want to create a view with the above query

Comment: The error is in this line :

 (SUM(MAX(CT.TotalAmount + CT.TotalTax + CT.Freight)) OVER (ORDER BY CT.TransDate, CT.SuppTransID)) 

You need to add a Partition By [Field Name] Before the ORDER BY https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: Which version of `Sql server` you are using this will not work in versions prior to `sql server 2012`

Comment: am using Sql server 2008

Comment: is it possible to convert this query to linq

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you cannot have MAX functions in your CASE statements. MAX is an aggregate and needs a group by clause. Also OVER(ORDER BY columns) is not supported by SQL Server 2008.

```
USE [ERPV9]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwSupplierReport]
AS
SELECT
        CT.TransDate, 
        CASE    WHEN DN.DocNo IS NOT NULL 
                THEN DN.DocNo 
                ELSE CT.SupplierReference                           
        END AS DocNo,
        TT.TransTypeName AS [Description],
        RP.ChequeNo,
        CASE  WHEN CT.TransTypeID = 20 
              THEN CT.TotalAmount + CT.TotalTax + CT.Freight
              ELSE 0 
        END AS Debit, 
        CASE  WHEN CT.TransTypeID IN (21,22) 
              THEN CT.TotalAmount + CT.TotalTax + CT.Freight
              ELSE 0 
        END AS Credit
        --SUM(CT.TotalAmount + CT.TotalTax + CT.Freight) 
        --    OVER (ORDER BY CT.TransDate, CT.SuppTransID) AS Balance
FROM        SupplierTransactions CT
LEFT JOIN   DocumentNos DN 
            ON CT.CompanyID = DN.CompanyID 
            AND CT.TransTypeID = DN.TransTypeID 
            AND CT.TransNo = DN.TransNo
INNER JOIN TransactionTypes TT 
            ON CT.CompanyID = TT.CompanyID 
            AND CT.TransTypeID = TT.TransTypeID
LEFT JOIN   ReceiptsAndPayments RP 
            ON CT.CompanyID = RP.CompanyID 
            AND CT.TransTypeID = RP.TransTypeID 
            AND CT.TransNo = RP.TransNo
WHERE   CT.CompanyID = 'ccaa3e3f-4486-4465-b5a1-723f647ead17' 
        AND SupplierCode = 'SR0001 ' 
        AND TransDate >= '2013-3-26' 
        AND TransDate < '2015-2-27'
```

Comment: Thanks but still its showing **Incorrect syntax near 'order'**

Comment: Oh, I read in your comment that you're using SQL Server 2008. I don't think ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING is supported in that version. Try my new code

Comment: i tried but still coming a **Incorrect syntax near 'order'.**

Comment: I see. Turns out, SQL Server 2008 doesn't support OVER(ORDER BY columns). You're going to have to try a different method. Try googling cumulative sum. So try this new edit out.